# Aurelia: How to get user's window's username

Tags: windows, authentication, aurelia

I'm not sure if this is even possible. I need to be able to get the users windows username. We are all on an intranet, so I don't have to worry about cross platform issues.

Does Aurelia have windows authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aurelia runs completely in the browser, so it doesn't have any way to support windows auth (unless the browser supports it). But there's no reason you can't send the user's username via an API call.